# codeigniter sending email with logo not working

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm using CI version 3 and I'm using the built in email functionality to send an HTML email template.

My code is as following:

```
public function send_email($sendTo, $fromName, $fromEmail, $data, $subject) {
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $this->email->to($sendTo);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->attach(FCPATH . "images/logo.png", "inline");
    $content = array(
        'HTMLcontent' => $data
    );
    $body = $this->load->view('email_template.php', $content, TRUE);
    $this->email->message($body);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The FCPATH is ok it shows : /home/myuser/public_html/ and I have images folder inside public_html

email_template.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img src="cid:logo.png" width="144" height="76" border="0" alt="logo"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the email comes it shows with a missing logo as the image below

[image: missing logo]

Comment: Check the image path through console once. .

Comment: you first suggestion "base_url()" worked thanks

Comment: Welcome. .   . . .